How can I add a small (~1 V) voltage from a fast, 50-ohm signal generator (AWG) onto a high DC voltage (~500 V) signal?
I need to add a small (~1 V) voltage with DC and AC (but not exclusively AC) components from a signal generator to a high DC voltage, up to approx. 500 V.
Conceptually, the answer could look like connecting the two voltages into the inputs of a subtraction or addition circuit of an operational amplifier, where the small voltage is connected via an isolator (see attached sketch of a schematic.)

Is this feasible?  Do high-power op-amps and isolators (such as optocouplers) exist? What kinds of options are out there?
Edit: more information.
The load impedance is 1-10 GΩ, depending on the exact load "device".
The large-voltage dc signal doesn't vary over time. But it may vary depending on the choice of load "device", and it can be anywhere from 0 to 500 V.
The small-voltage signal is well described by a pulse train as in the second image, i.e. it is a dc offset that changes periodically in time. The time-dependent offset is not known in advance (and in principle may remain stable over long periods of time), and has a magnitude of the order of +-1 V. Not larger than +-10 V. Ideally, the large+small signal should be combined faster than 0.1 ... 1 ms, because that's the ideal periodicity for the amplitude change.


There are several ways to do it, but which is best rather depends on the load the output has to drive, what impedance it presents to the thing driving it. Does the DC output vary from 0 to 500 V? The AC component is easy, a coupling capacitor. Can the DC component be added by simply programming the 500 V adjustable DC source? Answer by editing the question, not below here in comments.

A 1 V battery in series?

In addition to  what Neil_UK1 asked, can you edit the question to give a better description of the signal generator output including frequency range, waveform shape, AC amplitude and DC offset? If you can tell us exactly what you're trying to accomplish we can give you better answers.

Thank you for your helpful comments. I've edited the question to hopefully answer all of your extra questions.
winny: I need to add an AWG signal onto the output of a high-voltage dc supply. Unfortunately, I cannot replace the AWG signal with a 1 V fixed voltage.

Have you thought about injecting the complex DC+AC signal from the AWG into the GND connection of the load instead of adding it directly to the 500VDC? In this case the load (1...10G) is always between the 500V DC source and the (low impedance) AWG so that only a negligible DC current is flowing into the generator.

I wont vouch for the safety of this suggestion, so I am obliged to make the disclaimer that if you build this and it harms you or your equipment, I am not responsible in any way:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This uses a current sink to translate the signal \$V_{LO}\$ at LO upwards by many hundreds of volts. Q1 and R2 form the sink, in a closed loop around OA1 for precise current control, making \$V_X = V_{LO}\$. Current \$I\$ is therefore a function of input \$V_{LO}\$:
$$ I = \frac{V_{LO}}{R_2} $$
This same current is shared by R3 at the high side, and R3 will develop the same voltage across it as R2. Therefore potential \$V_Y\$ at Y is:
$$ V_Y = V_{HI} - V_{LO} $$
Obviously there is a huge potential difference between X and Y, meaning that Q1 will have to be special, able to tolerate \$V_{DS} > 500V\$.
With inputs \$V_{HI}\$ (blue) going between +480V and +500V, and \$V_{LO}\$ (orange) between 0V and +4V:

this is the output \$V_Z\$:

Since load impedance exceeds R3 by a factor of 104, it can be connected directly between Y and ground, without significantly affecting \$V_Y\$. For heavier loads, say 10M or lower, buffering would be necessary, which I do here with emitter follower Q2:

simulate this circuit
Transistor Q2 isn't anything special, so I protect it with clamps D1 and D2, to ensure it never "sees" a potential differences exceeding 12V. Resistor R4 permanently loads the output slightly, to keep the transistor properly biased even when there's no attached external load. R4 really should consist of several smaller resistors in series, to share the 500V between them.
Q2 will "lose" a further 0.6V between its base and emitter, so:
$$ V_{Z} = V_{HI} - V_{LO} - 0.6V $$

The typical way to do this is with a passive circuit known as a bias tee. In its simplest form it looks like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The inductor should be chosen to have a high impedance at the signal frequency, and the capacitor chosen to have a low impedance at the signal frequency. The capacitor, of course, has to be rated for the full DC voltage.
The inductor can be replaced with a resistor, but that reduces the filtering effectiveness and limits the maximum current the DC supply can provide to the output.

"I need to add a small (~1 V) voltage with DC and AC (but not exclusively AC) components"
If the signal has a DC component a bias T won't work.

Exactly as GodJihyo said: unfortunately, the small, potentially fast-changing signal can have a dc offset and hence bias tee doesn't do the trick here. Thanks though!
